# Regex.Split not keeping newline

Tags: c#, split, newline, delimiter

I am trying to split a string based on either `\n` `\r` `\r\n` but i do not want to *remove* them from the string

I know `Regex.Split` can *keep delimiter* but some how it is removing them

String Content

```
string contentString = @"幘䄍ਫ਼䱌㈰ぞ䙓ഊ幃噎ഊ幃䤱㝞䙏㈵ⰳ㕞䅁丬ㄲⰷ幆ㄶ幆䐀吀栀椀猀 昀漀爀洀愀琀 琀攀猀琀猀㨀幆匠ഊ幃䤱㝞䙏㈵ⰵ㕞䅁丬ㄲⰷ幆ㄶ幆䐀倀䐀䘀㐀㄀㜀 ⠀䈀㜀⤀Ⰰ 䴀漀搀攀㨀 　Ⰰ 䌀䤀㈀㤀 眀椀琀栀 瘀愀氀椀搀 挀栀愀爀愀挀琀攀爀猀 幆匍ਫ਼䍉ㄷ幆伲㔬㤵幂㝎ⰵⰬⰬⱞ䘱㙞䙄01234>A>B>CABC<A<B<C^䙓ഊ幈䌍ਫ਼塚
^FX CRC Block No 1 ^FS
਍ਫ਼塁ഊ幌䰲〰幆匍ਫ਼䍖不ਫ਼䍉ㄷ幆伲㔬㌵幁䅎ⰱ㈬㝞䘱㙞䙄This format tests:^䙓ഊ幃䤱㝞䙏㈵ⰵ㕞䅁丬ㄲⰷ幆ㄶ幆䐀倀䐀䘀㐀㄀㜀 ⠀䈀㜀⤀Ⰰ 䴀漀搀攀㨀 　Ⰰ 䌀䤀㈀㤀 眀椀琀栀 椀渀瘀愀氀椀搀 挀栀愀爀愀挀琀攀爀猀 幆匍ਫ਼䍉ㄷ幆伲㔬㤵幂㝎ⰵⰬⰬⱞ䘱㙞䙄01234þ>A>B>CABC<A<B<C^䙓ഊ幈䌍ਫ਼塚
^FX CRC Block No 2 ^FS
਍ਫ਼塁ഊ幌䰲〰幆匍ਫ਼䍖复ਫ਼䍉ㄷ幆伲㔬㌵幁䅎ⰱ㈬㝞䘱㙞䙄This format tests:^䙓ഊ幃䤱㝞䙏㈵ⰵ㕞䅁丬ㄲⰷ幆ㄶ幆䐀倀䐀䘀㐀㄀㜀 ⠀䈀㜀⤀Ⰰ 䴀漀搀攀㨀 　Ⰰ 䌀䤀㈀㤀 眀椀琀栀 瘀愀氀椀搀 挀栀愀爀愀挀琀攀爀猀Ⰰ 愀渀搀 挀漀搀攀 瘀愀氀椀搀愀琀椀漀渀 ⠀䌀嘀⤀ 幆匍ਫ਼䍉ㄷ幆伲㔬㤵幂㝎ⰵⰬⰬⱞ䘱㙞䙄01234>A>B>CABC<A<B<C^䙓ഊ幈䌍ਫ਼塚
^FX CRC Block No 3 ^FS
਍ਫ਼塁ഊ幌䰲〰幆匍ਫ਼䍖复ਫ਼䍉ㄷ幆伲㔬㌵幁䅎ⰱ㈬㝞䘱㙞䙄This format tests:^䙓ഊ幃䤱㝞䙏㈵ⰵ㕞䅁丬ㄲⰷ幆ㄶ幆䐀倀䐀䘀㐀㄀㜀 ⠀䈀㜀⤀Ⰰ 䴀漀搀攀㨀 　Ⰰ 䌀䤀㈀㤀 眀椀琀栀 椀渀瘀愀氀椀搀 挀栀愀爀愀挀琀攀爀猀Ⰰ 愀渀搀 挀漀搀攀 瘀愀氀椀搀愀琀椀漀渀⠀䌀嘀⤀ 幆匍ਫ਼䍉ㄷ幆伲㔬㤵幂㝎ⰵⰬⰬⱞ䘱㙞䙄01234þ>A>B>CABC<A<B<C^䙓ഊ幈䌍ਫ਼塚
^FX CRC Block No 4 ^FS
ਫ਼䙘⨪⨪⨪⨪⨪⨪⨪⨪⨪⨪⨪⨪⨪⨪⨪⨪⨪⨪⨪⨪⨪⨪⨪⨪⨪⨪⨪⨪⨪⨪⨪⨪⨪⨪⨪⨪⨪⨪⨪⨪⨪⨪⨪⨪⨪⩞䙓"
```

Expression using

```
  Regex.Split(contentString, "\n|\r\n|\r");
```

Please help me to do it

Thanks in advance
Monika

Comment: Try using *grouping* `(...)` for delimeters preserving: `var result = Regex.Split(contentString, "(\n|\r\n|\r)");`

Comment: Can you explain in detail ??Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should add *capturing parentheses* into the pattern:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.split?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Text_RegularExpressions_Regex_Split_System_String_System_String_

> If **capturing parentheses** are used in a `Regex.Split` expression, any
>   **captured text is included** in the resulting string array. For example,
>   if you split the string "plum-pear" on a hyphen placed within
>   capturing parentheses, the returned array includes a string element
>   that contains the hyphen.

(**bold** is mine)

In your case, to split

```
string contentString = @"幘䄍ਫ਼䱌㈰ぞ䙓ഊ幃噎ഊ幃䤱㝞䙏㈵ⰳ㕞䅁丬ㄲⰷ幆ㄶ幆䐀吀栀椀猀 昀漀爀洀愀琀 琀攀猀琀猀㨀幆匠ഊ幃䤱㝞䙏㈵ⰵ㕞䅁丬ㄲⰷ幆ㄶ幆䐀倀䐀䘀㐀㄀㜀 ⠀䈀㜀⤀Ⰰ 䴀漀搀攀㨀 　Ⰰ 䌀䤀㈀㤀 眀椀琀栀 瘀愀氀椀搀 挀栀愀爀愀挀琀攀爀猀 幆匍ਫ਼䍉ㄷ幆伲㔬㤵幂㝎ⰵⰬⰬⱞ䘱㙞䙄01234>A>B>CABC<A<B<C^䙓ഊ幈䌍ਫ਼塚
^FX CRC Block No 1 ^FS
਍ਫ਼塁ഊ幌䰲〰幆匍ਫ਼䍖不ਫ਼䍉ㄷ幆伲㔬㌵幁䅎ⰱ㈬㝞䘱㙞䙄This format tests:^䙓ഊ幃䤱㝞䙏㈵ⰵ㕞䅁丬ㄲⰷ幆ㄶ幆䐀倀䐀䘀㐀㄀㜀 ⠀䈀㜀⤀Ⰰ 䴀漀搀攀㨀 　Ⰰ 䌀䤀㈀㤀 眀椀琀栀 椀渀瘀愀氀椀搀 挀栀愀爀愀挀琀攀爀猀 幆匍ਫ਼䍉ㄷ幆伲㔬㤵幂㝎ⰵⰬⰬⱞ䘱㙞䙄01234þ>A>B>CABC<A<B<C^䙓ഊ幈䌍ਫ਼塚
^FX CRC Block No 2 ^FS
਍ਫ਼塁ഊ幌䰲〰幆匍ਫ਼䍖复ਫ਼䍉ㄷ幆伲㔬㌵幁䅎ⰱ㈬㝞䘱㙞䙄This format tests:^䙓ഊ幃䤱㝞䙏㈵ⰵ㕞䅁丬ㄲⰷ幆ㄶ幆䐀倀䐀䘀㐀㄀㜀 ⠀䈀㜀⤀Ⰰ 䴀漀搀攀㨀 　Ⰰ 䌀䤀㈀㤀 眀椀琀栀 瘀愀氀椀搀 挀栀愀爀愀挀琀攀爀猀Ⰰ 愀渀搀 挀漀搀攀 瘀愀氀椀搀愀琀椀漀渀 ⠀䌀嘀⤀ 幆匍ਫ਼䍉ㄷ幆伲㔬㤵幂㝎ⰵⰬⰬⱞ䘱㙞䙄01234>A>B>CABC<A<B<C^䙓ഊ幈䌍ਫ਼塚
^FX CRC Block No 3 ^FS
਍ਫ਼塁ഊ幌䰲〰幆匍ਫ਼䍖复ਫ਼䍉ㄷ幆伲㔬㌵幁䅎ⰱ㈬㝞䘱㙞䙄This format tests:^䙓ഊ幃䤱㝞䙏㈵ⰵ㕞䅁丬ㄲⰷ幆ㄶ幆䐀倀䐀䘀㐀㄀㜀 ⠀䈀㜀⤀Ⰰ 䴀漀搀攀㨀 　Ⰰ 䌀䤀㈀㤀 眀椀琀栀 椀渀瘀愀氀椀搀 挀栀愀爀愀挀琀攀爀猀Ⰰ 愀渀搀 挀漀搀攀 瘀愀氀椀搀愀琀椀漀渀⠀䌀嘀⤀ 幆匍ਫ਼䍉ㄷ幆伲㔬㤵幂㝎ⰵⰬⰬⱞ䘱㙞䙄01234þ>A>B>CABC<A<B<C^䙓ഊ幈䌍ਫ਼塚
^FX CRC Block No 4 ^FS
ਫ਼䙘⨪⨪⨪⨪⨪⨪⨪⨪⨪⨪⨪⨪⨪⨪⨪⨪⨪⨪⨪⨪⨪⨪⨪⨪⨪⨪⨪⨪⨪⨪⨪⨪⨪⨪⨪⨪⨪⨪⨪⨪⨪⨪⨪⨪⨪⩞䙓";
```

Instead of the original `"\n|\r\n|\r"` pattern you can put the same one but with capturing parentheses: `"(\n|\r\n|\r)"` i.e.

```
  string[] parts = Regex.Split(contentString, "(\n|\r\n|\r)");
```